# what is meaning of /bin/chown -Rf ownername:groupname path

Tags: unix, chmod

I was checking for some configuration and found this. Can any one help me in explaining meaning of `/bin/chown -Rf ownername:groupname folderpath`?

Comment: `chown` is a command for `changing file owner and group`. `-R`  means recursively. `-f` means suppressing error messages. For more info: `man chown`

Comment: I would like to know by giving -Rf together what will it do? Will let provide us information on errors that we are getting recursively on path mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

ex;

sample files and folder;

```
user@user:/tmp/1$ ls -arlt
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 Tem 28 14:29 test1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 Tem 28 14:29 test2
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user  4096 Tem 28 14:30 folder


user@user:/tmp/1$ ls -arlt folder/
---------- 1 user user    0 Tem 28 14:30 test1
```

without any parameter; error messages show as below;

```
user@user:/tmp/1$ find . -type f -name "*" | xargs chown bin.bin
chown: changing ownership of ‘./folder/test1’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘./test2’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘./test1’: Operation not permitted
```

-f suppressing this mesage, and
-R also change test1 file in folder.

```
user@user:/tmp/1$ find . -type f -name "*" | xargs sudo chown -Rf bin.bin
[sudo] password for user: 
user@user:/tmp/1$ ls -lart
total 80
-rw-rw-r--  1 bin    bin        0 Tem 28 14:29 test1
-rw-rw-r--  1 bin    bin        0 Tem 28 14:29 test2
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user  4096 Tem 28 14:30 folder

user@user:/tmp/1/folder$ ls -arlt
total 8
---------- 1 bin    bin       0 Tem 28 14:30 test1
```